# how to add package as external so it doesnt get budled by webpack

Tags: webpack, next.js, next.js13

i am trying to avoid webpack bundling chrome-aws-lambda package but i dont know how to do it in next.config.js, you can easily add it as externals in webpack.config.js , but how do you do it in next ?

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  webpack: (config, options) => {
    config.res
    config.module.rules.push({
      externals: ["chrome-aws-lambda"],
      // regex for the files that are problematic
      test: /.js$/,
      use: "unlazy-loader",
    });

    return config;
  },
};

module.exports = nextConfig;
```

this doesnt work